# How to use "ol" HTML tag in android Textview

Tags: android, html, webview, textview

How to display "ol" HTML tag in android Textview. I already use Webview widget and it's working fine but I want to use Textview for display HTML content.

Comment: After lots of searching, I found some supporting tag.

https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2017/09/29/android-html-textview/#.XU1OU_kzaUl

https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410675/supported-html-tags-on-android-textview

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your textview

```html
 TextView yourTextView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);        
 
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p align=right> <b> "+ "I am humman" + "  </b> </p>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend this：

HtmlCompat.fromHtml("Forgotten password", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

Answer (score -1):

You can display "ol" HTML tag with the following code.

```
val displayText = Html.fromHtml(
        "<ol>\n" +
        "<li>First</li>\n" +
        "<li>Second</li>\n" +
        "<li>Third</li>\n" +
        "<li>Fourth</li>\n" +
        "<li>Fifth</li>\n" +
        "</ol>"
)
displayTextView.text = txt
```

Comment: No, because the tag isn't supported. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML