# Jetpack compose bold only string placeholder

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a string resource like this

```
<string name="my_string">Fancy string with an %1$s placeholder</string>
```

and I would like to have this as output: "Fancy string with an **amazing** placeholder". Which is the string with the content of the placeholder in bold.

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Finally I got the desired result with

```kotlin
val placeholder = "Amazing"

val globalText = stringResource(id = R.string.my_string, placeholder)

val start = globalText.indexOf(placeholder)
val spanStyles = listOf(
    AnnotatedString.Range(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
        start = start,
        end = start + placeholder.length
    )
)
Text(text = AnnotatedString(text = globalText, spanStyles = spanStyles))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Use this**

```
    @Composable
fun MultipleStylesInText() {
    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue)) {
                append("H")
            }
            append("ello ")

            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Red)) {
                append("W")
            }
            append("orld")
        }
    )
}
```

output - [outputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD5qn.png)

src - [github](https://github.com/android/snippets/blob/13a17cb1d733c6fb80db742c3ab6c072793afbb5/compose/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/compose/snippets/text/TextSnippets.kt#L123-L126) /or/ [developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text)

Comment: This will make whole string bold, not just the inserted part

Comment: ok. so you can take reference from here, \n @Composable
fun MultipleStylesInText() {
    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue)) {
                append("H")
            }
            append("ello ")

            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Red)) {
                append("W")
            }
            append("orld")
        }
    )
}

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of posting improvements in the comments

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a slightly more flexible and reusable solution in my point of view, as the solutions quoted above are not working if we have several place holders

```
@Composable
fun annotateRecursively(
    placeHolderList: List<Pair<String, SpanStyle>>,
    originalText: String
): AnnotatedString {
    var annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString { append(originalText) }
    for (item in placeHolderList) {
        annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            val startIndex = annotatedString.indexOf(item.first)
            val endIndex = startIndex + item.first.length
            append(annotatedString)
            addStyle(style = item.second, start = startIndex, end = endIndex)
        }
    }
    return annotatedString
}
```

This basically takes a list of `Pair` precising the `placeholder` and a `SpanStyle` (instead of a `Pair` it can be a custom `data class` if you need anything else...)

Then iterate over the `list` to annotate the `string` with the corresponding `SpanStyle` to their placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75823571/14484575) I created this compose

```
@Composable
fun textMultiStyle(
    originalText: String,
    customTextList: List<TextWithStyle>
): AnnotatedString {
    var annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString { append(originalText) }

    customTextList.forEach { textExcerpt ->
        annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            val startIndex = annotatedString.indexOf(textExcerpt.customText)
            val endIndex = startIndex + textExcerpt.customText.length
            append(annotatedString)
            addStyle(
                style = textExcerpt.style.toSpanStyle(),
                start = startIndex,
                end = endIndex
            )
        }
    }
    return annotatedString
}

data class TextWithStyle(
    val customText: String,
    val style: TextStyle
)

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
    Text(
        text = textMultiStyle(
            originalText = "Quero esse trecho normal, esse em negrito, esse normal e esse em negrito laranja",
            customTextList = listOf(
                TextWithStyle(
                    customText = "esse em negrito",
                    style = MDSTextStyle.paragraph5
                ),
                TextWithStyle(
                    customText = "esse em negrito laranja",
                    style = MDSTextStyle.paragraph5.copy(color = PrimaryPure)
                ),
            )
        ),
        style = MDSTextStyle.paragraph4
    )
}
```

Output:

[image: out]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are displaying this in a Text composable, do this. Make sure to include a backslash before the $ character:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()) {
    val s = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.my_string)
    val p = s.indexOf("%1\$s")
    Text(s.substring(0, p))
    Text("amazing", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
    Text(s.substring(p + 4))
}
```

Comment: I cannot modify the string resource

Comment: You didn't indicate that you could not modify the resource. You also didn't indicate how this text is being displayed. I'll assume it's with a Text composable. I updated my solution above.

Answer (score -1):

Previous comments are too complicated.
It's enough to use html tags in your string resource:

```
<string name="my_string">Fancy string with an <b>amazing</b> <i>placeholder</i></string>
```

If you are use Composable - you can use buildAnnotatedString for some cases. Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#multiple-styles)

```
Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Red)) {
                append("W")
            }
            append("orld")
        }
    )
```