# AlertDialog does not display body text

Tags: android

I am using an `AlertDialog()` to display a dialog for about in my app. I tried, adding html text to my `Strings resource`. And I am accessing this below. But, for some unknown reason nothing is rendering out. Text is just some simple *lorem ipsum*.

```
AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                tosVisible = false
            },
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
            title = {
                Text(text = "About this app")
            },
            text = {
                SelectionContainer{
                    TextView(context).setText(Html.fromHtml(stringResource(R.string.about_app), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT))
                }
            },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        tosVisible = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Confirm")
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        tosVisible = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            }
        )
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `alert.show()` and the eventual `alert.cancel()` are working correctly?

Comment: if you already have answer, just post your own answer not in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer, its work for me.
just call the HtmlText function from the SelectionContainer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397058/7248394

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
     text = Html.fromHtml(stringResource(R.string.about_app), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString())
```

*Use `Text` under compose. Instead of `TextView`.*