# Adding line break to AnnotatedString from HTML tags

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I found a very good solution here about highlighting HTML tags and manipulating them on text: [Android Compose: How to use HTML tags in a Text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494838/android-compose-how-to-use-html-tags-in-a-text-view)

Here is the actual solution in code:

```
/**
     * Converts a [Spanned] into an [AnnotatedString] trying to keep as much formatting as possible.
     *
     * Currently supports `bold`, `italic`, `underline` and `color`.
     */
    fun Spanned.toAnnotatedString(): AnnotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        val spanned = this@toAnnotatedString
        append(spanned.toString())
        getSpans(0, spanned.length, Any::class.java).forEach { span ->
            val start = getSpanStart(span)
            val end = getSpanEnd(span)
            when (span) {
                is StyleSpan -> when (span.style) {
                    Typeface.BOLD -> addStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold), start, end)
                    Typeface.ITALIC -> addStyle(SpanStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic), start, end)
                    Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC -> addStyle(SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic), start, end)
                }
                is UnderlineSpan -> addStyle(SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline), start, end)
                is ForegroundColorSpan -> addStyle(SpanStyle(color = Color(span.foregroundColor)), start, end)
            }
        }
    }
```

But my question is: how can this function be improved so that it also reads the line break character "\n" and performs this line break?

Comment: compose text view recognizes /n just add that tag to your spannable string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **this code**:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
fun htmlText(htmlText: String): AnnotatedString =
Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toAnnotatedString()
```