How to render html text in Text() - Compose Multilatform targeting Android, iOS, Desktop, Web
Is there any way to render html text in compose multiplatform targeting all platforms (android, ios, desktop, web)?

What is "html text"? Do you want to display an HTML page? Do you want to display richt text that is formatted with some HTML tags? Do you want to create HTML code from some internal richt text representation like AnnotatedString? Please provide a short example of what you try to achieve to better demonstrate what you are looking for.

i want to display text with html tags in it.. example input: "Welcome back XYZYour portfolio is PQR ...."

No, That's specially for android not compose multiplatform solution.

The question may be, but not this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241339/6216216
